# Code Academy Java Script course Building an Address Book 3/6

Tags: javascript, addressbook

I'm trying to keep up with the instructions described here:[Building an Address Book](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/building-an-address-book/0/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#)

& that's the result:

```
var bob = {
firstName: "Bob",
lastName: "Jones",
phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

// printPerson added here
function printPerson(person){
    console.log( contacts[person].firstName + " " + contacts[person].lastName )
};

printPerson(0);
printPerson(1);
```

Is there something wrong with my function or the input argument?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some question which you failed to write, there is nothing wrong with your function or arguments and it's working as it should!

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

Code quality can be the point of discussion here, as instead of doing `contacts = [bob, mary];` you can use

```
contacts.push(bob);
contacts.push(mary);
```

So when you need to add another contact it'll be easier this way, what you have done is more static. Also to print all the persons, you can use the loop inside `printPerson` instead of calling it twice:

```
function printPerson(){
    for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        console.log(contacts[i].firstName + " " + contacts[i].lastName);
}
```

In order to pass the test, you will have to do this according to their instructions:

```
function printPerson(person){
    console.log( person.firstName + " " + person.lastName );
}

printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

They asked you to pass the person object in the function whereas you were passing the index.

Comment: you can vote up and mark the answer correct if it helped. thanks

Comment: Well I tried to vote it up, but without reputation it can't happen.sorry.

Comment: yea you'll have to wait for a while, try in half an hour

Answer (score 1):

When use type printPerson(0), this 0 has no relation to contacts, right? Hence your code is incorrect.

You need to pass contacts[0] and contacts[1] as arguments. How else do you expect the function to get the values Bob and Mary?

Here's the code that fixes the issue:

```
function printPerson(person){
    console.log( person.firstName + " " + person.lastName )
};

printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

Comment: That's why I really didn't understand why I can't pass the test.

Comment: sorry, my bad.. just checked those instructions.. see my edited answer now i've added what they asked

Comment: Azee, When use type printPerson(0), this 0 has no relation to contacts, right? Hence your code is incorrect.
@AbdulJabbar: You've downvoted my answer and added the same code in your answer

Comment: yea im sorry i didnt check their instructions first, now it wont let me upvote untill you edit the answer.. so edit it a bit so i could upvote.. as i said, my bad